# Can't get stored python integer back in java in habase google cloud

Tags: java, python, hbase, google-cloud-dataproc

I'm using hbase over google cloud bigtable to store my bigdata. I have 2 programs. first, store data using python into hbase and the second, read those info back from java by connecting to the same endpoint.

so from python interactive shell I can read byte arrays back into an integer (command 15)

```
In [13]: row.cells['stat']['viewability'][0].value 
Out[13]: '\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00A'

In [14]: len(row.cells['stat']['viewability'][0].value) 
Out[14]: 8

In [15]: struct.unpack('>Q', row.cells['stat']['viewability'][0].value) 
Out[15]: (65,)
```

but I can't read back the same byte array into java Integer data type
I'm using the following in java

```
byte[] columnFamilyBytes = Bytes.toBytes("stat");
byte[] viewabilityColumnBytes = Bytes.toBytes("viewability");
Integer viewability = Bytes.toInt(c1.getValue(columnFamilyBytes, viewabilityColumnBytes));
```

and I'm getting NULL in response.

Comment: Is it correct to say that c1 is an HBase Result object? If so, can you verify that a stat:viewability cell exists within the Result (simplest way appears to be printing out the result of c1.toString(), assuming the result isn't huge).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem
the column stored as long value so I had to first read it as long in java and then convert it to int